# R: incorrect timestamps returned from merge.zoo

Tags: r

Basically, I have the following code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(time=c(42688.375,42688.3784722222,42688.3819444444,42688.3854166667,42688.3888888889,42688.3923611111,42688.3958333333,42688.3993055556,42688.4027777778,42688.40625,42688.4097222222,42688.4131944444,42688.4166666667),value=c(1:13))


df2 <- data.frame(time=c(42688.375,42688.3770833333,42688.3791666667,42688.38125,42688.3833333333,42688.3854166667,42688.3875,42688.3895833333,42688.3916666667,42688.39375,42688.3958333333,42688.3979166667,42688.4,42688.4020833333,42688.4041666667,42688.40625,42688.4083333333,42688.4104166667,42688.4125,42688.4145833333,42688.4166666667),value=c(1:21))

df1[,1] <- as.POSIXct(df1[,1]*(60*60*24),origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT")
df2[,1] <- as.POSIXct(df2[,1]*(60*60*24),origin="1899-12-30",tz="GMT")

z1 <- read.zoo(df1)
z2 <- read.zoo(df2)
```

The output of z1 is as follow:

```
2016-11-14 09:00:00 2016-11-14 09:04:59 2016-11-14 09:09:59 
                  1                   2                   3 
2016-11-14 09:15:00 2016-11-14 09:20:00 2016-11-14 09:24:59 
                  4                   5                   6 
2016-11-14 09:29:59 2016-11-14 09:35:00 2016-11-14 09:40:00 
                  7                   8                   9 
2016-11-14 09:45:00 2016-11-14 09:49:59 2016-11-14 09:54:59 
                 10                  11                  12 
2016-11-14 10:00:00 
                 13
```

The output for z2 is as follow:

```
2016-11-14 09:00:00 2016-11-14 09:02:59 2016-11-14 09:06:00 
                  1                   2                   3 
2016-11-14 09:09:00 2016-11-14 09:11:59 2016-11-14 09:15:00 
                  4                   5                   6 
2016-11-14 09:17:59 2016-11-14 09:20:59 2016-11-14 09:24:00 
                  7                   8                   9 
2016-11-14 09:27:00 2016-11-14 09:29:59 2016-11-14 09:33:00 
                 10                  11                  12 
2016-11-14 09:36:00 2016-11-14 09:38:59 2016-11-14 09:42:00 
                 13                  14                  15 
2016-11-14 09:45:00 2016-11-14 09:47:59 2016-11-14 09:51:00 
                 16                  17                  18 
2016-11-14 09:54:00 2016-11-14 09:56:59 2016-11-14 10:00:00 
                 19                  20                  21
```

Note that **both z1 and z2 cover the 9am - 10am period**. However, I merge the 2 zoo objects, the output all of a sudden jump to **5pm to 6pm**. I was expecting the output to display the "9am-10am" period not the latter one.

```
> merge.zoo(z1,z2)
                    z1 z2
2016-11-14 17:00:00  1  1
2016-11-14 17:02:59 NA  2
2016-11-14 17:04:59  2 NA
2016-11-14 17:06:00 NA  3
2016-11-14 17:09:00 NA  4
2016-11-14 17:09:59  3 NA
2016-11-14 17:11:59 NA  5
2016-11-14 17:15:00  4  6
2016-11-14 17:17:59 NA  7
2016-11-14 17:20:00  5 NA
2016-11-14 17:20:59 NA  8
2016-11-14 17:24:00 NA  9
2016-11-14 17:24:59  6 NA
2016-11-14 17:27:00 NA 10
2016-11-14 17:29:59  7 11
2016-11-14 17:33:00 NA 12
2016-11-14 17:35:00  8 NA
2016-11-14 17:36:00 NA 13
2016-11-14 17:38:59 NA 14
2016-11-14 17:40:00  9 NA
2016-11-14 17:42:00 NA 15
2016-11-14 17:45:00 10 16
2016-11-14 17:47:59 NA 17
2016-11-14 17:49:59 11 NA
2016-11-14 17:51:00 NA 18
2016-11-14 17:54:00 NA 19
2016-11-14 17:54:59 12 NA
2016-11-14 17:56:59 NA 20
2016-11-14 18:00:00 13 21
```

Can someone help me resolve this ? why is this happening ?

Comment: You should check the date of the "Fall back" of DST in your timezone.

Comment: Sorry, can you further elaborate please ? Can you write this as a solution please ?